# Записать float в экспоненциальной форме в файл

Tags: python, файлы, запись

Имеется число типа float, нужно представить его в экспоненциальной форме и записать в файл. Как это можно сделать?
Нужно использовать какой-то спецификатор? Если мне нужно просто записать float с какой-то точностью, как в таком случае поступить?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привести вид числа в экспоненциальный:

```
number = 12.123456789
exp_number = "{:.3e}".format(number)
```

Теперь можно сохранять в файл.

Число 3 - количество знаков после запятой.